# Docker run can't run python image- IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I have built docker image of my python file using docker-hub. When I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
$docker run -it docker/testservice /bin/sh
  File "run.py", line 38
    def docker():
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

If I run the same run.py manually with the same version of python, it works perfectly fine.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5.2

RUN ["pip", "install", "docker-cloud"]

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app/src/DockerService

EXPOSE 5002/tcp
ENV PYTHON_URLS http://*:5002

VOLUME /etc/test/

COPY default.conf /etc/test/

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "run.py"]
```

Is there any idea what the problem is?

Comment: you file run.py has an incorrect indentation, fix it

Comment: @user2915097 it doesn't seem so. Because I copy the same file and run it manually using $python run.py and it works fine.

Comment: there is something odd, if you `docker run ... /bin/sh`it should replace your entrypoint, and not launch your run.py

Comment: @user2915097 you mean I should remove /bin/sh from docker run cmd?

Comment: No, when you issue this command, you should have a shell prompt, and no error message as you just launch /bin/sh (so no relationship with any Python code)

Comment: @user2915097 No, `/bin/sh` is replacing `CMD` here, not `ENTRYPOINT`. The `ENTRYPOINT` runs first, and takes `CMD` as an argument list.

Comment: Ah yes, correct, should use `docker run -i -t --entrypoint=/bin/sh`

Comment: I still get the same error in the same line number although I changed it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task stopped because it has nothing more to do. A container only runs as long as it's doing something. docker ps -a command can be useful to checkout the containers.